# How to use an API in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get data from online sources, specifically to do with economics. The world bank API was simple to understand, however, I need to be able to retrieve data from the united nations, through the UNdata API: http://data.un.org/Host.aspx?Content=API
I am relatively inexperienced with VB.net, and don't really know where to start, and having googled around a bit and found no answers, I could really do with some help to get me off the ground. Thanks

Comment: It looks like the API given there is based on web access, so you'll need to look at things relating to `System.Net.WebRequest` and the `WebResponse` you get back from it.

Comment: thanks! that's a useful start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to consume the service is from the project in solution.

The link you provided has an ASMX service

> SOAP Web Service at http://data.un.org/ws/NSIStdV20Service.asmx

In your "Project" on your Visual studio solution, you will notice "references".
Right click on it, you see a context menu.

There, you select "Add Service Reference". In the window opened, enter the above service URL, after that you can start consuming it

You should enter the URL as `http://data.un.org/ws/NSIStdV20Service.asmx?wsdl`

Then a proxy class gets created, which you can consume.

Comment: Thanks for the help, would it be possible for you to elaborate further on how you can consume it, as I've not had experience with ASMX services before

Comment: After adding the service a proxy class gets created, for example "refrence.vb". Look for that class, It just looks like another VB class. Create an object using the class name/interface name and use it.